# TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to get the messages of an array of channel ids, and this is the code. The `console.log` does log the channel objects, so I know they're in there.  However, on running this, it returns the TypeError "Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined"

```
   console.log(filtered_channel_ids);
   filtered_channel_ids.forEach((element) => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(element);
    if (channel.messages) {
     channel.messages
      .fetch({limit: 10})
      .then((message) => console.log(message.content));
    }
   });
```

I've also tried catching the error, but it still won't return anything.

Comment: `element` is not a valid channel ID.

Comment: yes, make sure your channel IDs are actually correct.

Comment: @Lioness100 I tried element.id too, but that gives the same error. How would I get a valid channel ID?

Comment: There's not much to it except making sure the channel ID corresponds to an existing channel that the bot has cached.

Comment: What's the value of `filtered_channel_ids`?